# Excel VBA code to upload document into SharePoint online 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, excel, excel-services, vba

I'm looking for a snippet in VBA to upload a document (PDF file) into SharePoint online

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Dim SharepointAddress As String
Dim LocalAddress As String
Dim objNet As Object
Dim FS As Object

' Where you will enter Sharepoint location path
SharepointAddress = "\\sharepoint path to document library"  & "\" 
 ' Where you will enter the file path, ex: Excel file
LocalAddress = "your file path"                                     
Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If FS.FileExists(LocalAddress) Then
FS.CopyFile LocalAddress, SharepointAddress
End If
Set objNet = Nothing
Set FS = Nothing
```

Comment: Must try this !! Thanks a load !!

Answer (score 0):

Also, need to make sure "Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library" is turned on.

[Creating a reference of Microsoft Scripting Runtime Library](https://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/filesystemobject-in-vba/)

Answer (score -1):

Just to add I have recently used this solution and it worked.
The hardest part was mapping the sharepoint to a network drive as I didn't have elevated permissions.

The link below helped with this.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2616712

I had much less luck with solutions found elsewhere which mapped and then removed network drives in the sub.